# PostgreSQL Query to get the output from same table with same table values

Tags: postgresql

I have one table

```
id  employee    leave_days  leave_type  type
1   ABC                 10       sick   remove
2   ABC                 20       sick   add
3   ABC                 15     Annual   remove
4   ABC                 50     Annual   add
5   XYZ                 10       sick   remove
6   XYZ                 20       sick   add
7   XYZ                 15     Annual   remove
8   XYZ                 50     Annual   add
```

From the above table I will group by the column name called **leave_type** and then I will merge rows and the output should be as follows.

I have to group by column name **leave_type** and add new column called **leave_allocated** . In the **leave_allocated** column, the column **type** with value **add** only will come.

```
id  employee    leave_days  leave_type  leave_allocated
1   ABC             10          sick    20
2   ABC             15        Annual    50
3   XYZ             10          sick    20
4   XYZ             15        Annual    50
```

I tried with sub query I could not match the inner query with outer query .

Comment: can't see any difference between your sample data and expected output.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal Yeah wrongly typed..Thanks

Comment: Tag the database correctly, surely you are not using 3 databases to store leave information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help

```
SELECT id,
    employee,
    leave_dates,
    leave type,
    (SELECT leave_days
    FROM TABLE t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    AND t2.type = 'add'
    ) leave_allocated
FROM TABLE t1
WHERE t1.type = 'remove'
```

Comment: select DISTINCT employee_id, (select sum(number_of_days_temp) from hr_holidays t2 
     where t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id and t2.type = 'remove' 
    and t2.holiday_status_id = t1.holiday_Status_id)taken,
holiday_status_id,
(select sum(number_of_days_temp) from hr_holidays t2 
    where t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id and t2.type = 'add' 
    and t2.holiday_status_id = t1.holiday_Status_id)allocated
 from hr_holidays t1 where  t1.employee_id =2
 group by t1.id,t1.holiday_Status_id         ... I tried with your reference and It works...thanks @Sudipta Mondal